# How to align a dataframe column header when writing csv file in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs

In dataframe for each column III am assigning fixed width and and storing back to HDFS, but problem is I am not getting proper alignment

Here is my code:

```
val hdfs=spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/akshathasai/fixedwidth.csv").toDF()
hdfs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val widths=Array(15,3,10)
widths: Array[Int] = Array(15, 3, 10)

scala> val df=hdfs.columns.zip(widths).foldLeft(hdfs){ (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x._1,rpad(trim(col(x._1).cast("string")),x._2," "))}
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, age: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","\t").save("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/akshathasai/sai3/fw21")
```

output in HDFS looking like below:

```
Name age    phonenumber
akshatha    27  9900090252
amrutha 28  9900902423
sharath 29  9900902878
```

I want output should look like below

```
Name            age  phonenumber
akshatha        27   9900090252
amrutha         28   9900902423
sharath         29   9900902878
```

Comment: Are you able to read dataframe back from the output csv?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this?, if you are using **Spark** and **HDFS**, then your _CSV_ should be really BIG. Big enough to don't be intended for human reading/processing, additionally since the file is big adding white spaces _(that will increase the file size, and thus reading time when reprocessing it)_ just for _pretty printing_  seems like a bad idea to me. Now, if this is a final _"report"_ output... you may do that formatting in Python, Scala, Java or any other language you are familiar with, or importing it to an Excel spreed sheet _(executives love that LOL)_.

Comment: How exactly are you viewing the output in HDFS?  Hue? console command?  The issue here is not the delimiter, but the display is not aligning the tabs correctly because the tab size is too small.

Comment: This is I am trying with sample input file actually this need to work on terabytes of data, just here checking for sample output in hdfs, I am viewing output in hdfs

Comment: Once I store the data in hdfs as I expected which is already shown output which should have proper alignment that gonna use by some legacy systems so they this requirement to me. Can please tell how to do formatting in scala to get proper alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Spark [`csv` writer provides following options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@csv(path:String):Unit):

> - ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace (default true): a flag indicating whether or not leading whitespaces from values being written should be skipped.
> - ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace (default true): a flag indicating defines whether or not trailing whitespaces from values being written should be skipped.

which in your case should be set to `false`, i.e.

```
 df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv")
   .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false")
   .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false")
   ...
   .save()
```